# MVC 5 / Bootstrap App - Modal Dialog Auto expand?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the following HTML in an MVC 5 / Bootstrap app. As you can see, I am attempting to display a photo in the modal dialog. This works fine. But, if the photo is wider than the dialog, it extends beyond the bounds of the dialog. Is there a way I can have the dialog expand, to a certain point, then display scroll bars, based on the size of the contents (image)?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="viewPhotoDialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Ask the Experts</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { askTheExpertId = @Model.AskTheExpertId })" alt="" title=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Boostrap Modal component is not intended to be used as a lightbox. It's mostly about providing alerts and other dialogs. If you want to show photos, a gallery, etc., I'd recommend going with a true lightbox solution. Magnific Popup is a really great, responsive one: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.img-responsive` class to the img (gives max-width:100% and auto height).
About modal width, there are 2 extra option classes `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` that you can add at `.modal-dialog`
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals